# Simulink: Use array of structs or a cell matrix

Tags: simulink

I have an array of polyhedron objects (A matrix A and vector b that describe a region x in N dimensional space such that A*x <= b). I have like 600 or so polyhedrons in total.

I need to use these polyhedrons in my Simulink simulation. The A matricies and b vectors are not the same size, so I cannot create a 3d tensor of A matricies or a 2d matrix of b vectors (unless I added 0s to them to resized them all to the largest one, but I'm wondering if there is a better way).

I read that structure arrays and cell matricies are not allowed in Simulink. My question is if anyone knows any tricks to be able to easily use an array of variable sized matricies in Simulink? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. A structure field can be variable-sized, so a structure with variable-sized fields might be your solution.
2. Array of structures with extra parameter "n" that is used as a counter, to mimic variable-sized behaviour.
3. Do all mathematics and storage in a MATLAB Function block - which allows dynamic sizing.

Comment: Hm, I tried directly using a structure that has my polyhedron array as a struct, but SIMULINK still complained :(